# How to use Elasticsearch Marvel via vagrant?

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant, elasticsearch-marvel

I use vagrant (box with Ubuntu). I have Elasticsearch installed on it. It available at

```
localhost:9200
```

in my Ubuntu. Marvel available at

```
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/
```

How can I enter Marvel on my host? 
I usually use the following code to create virtual host for my sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName some.192.168.56.56.xip.io

    DocumentRoot /var/www/some

    <Directory /var/www/some>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/some-192.168.56.56.xip.io-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/some-192.168.56.56.xip.io-access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using virtual hosts at all.
The only things needed to work with elasticsearch via Vagrant:

1) 'config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9200, host: 9200' in Vagrantfile

2) Need to add 'network.bind_host: **0.0.0.0**' in ES config (I had 'localhost' here - that was my problem)

3) Restart Elasticsearch.

Comment: Had zero chance working this out by myself, so your answer is much appreciated :D